# java and apex output different crypto generateDigest SHA-512 method in apex and java logic not same

Tags: apex, java

Hi i write below apex code for encryption SHA-512

```
   public class TestSimple {
    Public TestSimple(){  
    }
    public void decrytMethod(){
        String key = 'This is string';
        Blob digest = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-512', Blob.valueOf(key));
        String s = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(digest);
        System.debug('Decrypt:'+s);
    }
}
```

It Give me output
Decrypt: **HUQXxm8VKM1ZMV/AnnZy40TX30IedtBUte4qsJuUb2IhyPJE8cLUvqExY+9gW7/f0z/M+M+YpZwTRBCB2Pt25Q==**

I want some logic in java but in java its give me wrong response..
like

```
public String get_SHA_512_SecureString(String plainText){
    try{
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    byte[] bytes = messageDigest.digest( plainText.getBytes() );
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++){
       sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
     return sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
        return "";
    }
}
```

In java its return 
**1d4417c66f1528cd59315fc09e7672e344d7df421e76d054b5ee2ab09b946f6221c8f244f1c2d4bea13163ef605bbfdfd33fccf8cf98a59c13441081d8fb76e5**

> I want java output is like apex output by passing same string side...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both languages are working fine. You are decoding them with wrong base.

`Apex` method is encoding `blob` as Base 64 and `Java` method is encoding it in Base 16. When you convert it in base 16 it output hex value of Blob. So, you should convert the value to hex by `EncodingUtil.convertToHex` as below.

```
public void decrytMethod()
{
        String key = 'This is string';
        Blob digest = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-512', Blob.valueOf(key));
        String s = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(digest);
        System.debug('Decrypt:'+s);
        System.assertEquals(s,'1d4417c66f1528cd59315fc09e7672e344d7df421e76d054b5ee2ab09b946f6221c8f244f1c2d4bea13163ef605bbfdfd33fccf8cf98a59c13441081d8fb76e5');
}
```

[image]